# Eclipse: Get the project name as a VM argument?

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, jvm-arguments

Consider a configuration class which needs to parse a different config file for each Eclipse project.

For instance, If `Configuration` class is called from `Project1`, it should parse `special/path/fileX`, and if it is being called from `Project2`, it should parse `special/path/fileY`.

I've tried [using Eclipse's `{project_name}`](http://it%20should%20parse%20%60special/path/fileX%60), but surprisingly it is being parsed to the project being highlighted by the cursor, not the parent project of the current class.

Any ideas how can I distinguish one project from another in Eclipse Runtime, preferably using JVM arguments?

Comment: Why aren't you passing the file path/name as a parameter from the invocation to the configuration class?

Comment: I don't understand the question, where is this code running? In the IDE, or is it an RCP app, or something else?

Comment: I want a single point of choice. The `Configuration` class is called from many class in the project - I want the ability to change the file for the entire project at once.

Comment: @FrancisUpton The code is running in the IDE. When it's in production, there's a special VM arg that tells the the `Configuration` class the exact path of the file.

Comment: One thing to consider is to look up the call stack at the calling class and maybe you can make the determination from that. This is pretty easy to do (new Exception().printStackTrace() or use the stack trace elements).

Comment: It might work, but it's a great abuse of the Exception mechanism.

Comment: Distinguish projects by the fact they have different `classpath`s, like `log4j` or Spring does.  Put the configuration file on the project's classpath so that each project has files with the same name but in different directories.  That is the "best practice" because it isolates `Configuration` from knowledge about the projects it is used in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a workaround to your described problem, but I guess it's a better solution as it's independent from Eclipse and will easily work in production too.

Simply load the same file from the classpath, regardless which Project you're starting this from:

```
/my/file/from/classpath.txt
```

But put this file only in Project1 / Project2, such that the various files mutually exclude themselves according to your set-up:

```
/Project1/src/my/file/from/classpath.txt
/Project2/src/my/file/from/classpath.txt
```

Where `src` are Java source folders. Now you can still use your JVM parameter to override this, or to provide a default if the above is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be using eclipse's run configurations. Simply create as many configurations as you want, supply all the JVM args you want, and use them to launch. This will also be very close to what you're going to do in production mode

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the user would need to define a different run configuration for each JUnit, which is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

or you can go to your Eclipse' Installed JRE's and have the configuration set as JVMArgs just the way you would have in prod.

If required, you can have diff copy of JREs per env.

Also if running from the IDE, you can get the 
    System.getProperty("user.dir") 
which should be the root of the project.

that system property can be used to track the callee. Better still, set the Installed JRE's JVM Args to be something like this

```
-Dtheflaginprod=${project_loc}

project_loc = absolute path of the the project (/usr/projects/project1)
project_path = project name relative to the workspace  (/project1)
```